# Have we found any other life form outside our planet?

Tags: evolution, life, astrobiology

I'm not asking about the possibility of formation of life on other planets instead has there been any real evidence of life(such as micro organisms or even very basic structures) that might suggest an evolutionary path(for example from asteroids that hit the earth or planets and other objects in the solar system)?

Comment: You really think there might be such evidence, but somebody’s keeping it from you?

Comment: @David No not really but I'm trying to get a good grasp of evolution and it seemed only logical that simple life form might exist even in our solar system and no recent exploration mission or revelation came to my mind!

Comment: You say you want to get a good grasp of evolution, but your concern seems to have nothing to do with evolution.  In essence you are asking whether life originated from non-living matter (abiogenesis) here on earth or somewhere else in the universe. The latter idea was proposed by astronomers (Bernard Lovell was one I seem to remember) — some would say because it provided an easy way of avoiding a difficult problem they were unable or unwilling to tackle. Do your own homework on that.

Answer (score 3):

No, there has been no evidence found of extraterrestrial or off-Earth life, at least as publicly-shared information. Via [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/):

> [No life beyond Earth has ever been found](https://astrobiology.nasa.gov/about/); there is no evidence that alien life has ever visited our planet.

Answer (score 2):

There is some debate about this, but there's a chance that we have found alien microbial fossils.  In 1984, a [meteorite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_Hills_84001#Hypothetical_biogenic_features) that originated on Mars was found in Antarctica.  In 1996, odd microscopic formations were found inside that resemble known fossils of bacteria.

The visual resemblance to fossils alone is not enough to prove it is truly evidence of alien life, but it's the most compelling piece of evidence we have now.

Comment: It seems controversial since there isn't just much data to support it but can we assume that further exploration on Mars could actually reveal the existence of extraterrestrial life?

Comment: @Matt It's possible, but currently there's no concrete evidence.